# SQL Server Update Value XML Node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have 2 tables in SQL Server

**Table1**

```
   ID   - Name  - Phone
   1      HK      999    
   2      RK      888
   3      SK      777
   4      PK      666
```

**Table2**

```
   ID   - XMLCol
   1      XMLVal1
```

XMLVal1

```
   <Root>
    <Data1>
     <ID>1</ID>
     <Name>HK</Name> 
     </Data1>
    <Data1>
     <ID>2</ID>
     <Name>RK</Name>
     </Data1>
    </Root>
```

Now I am inserting a GUID column into **Table1**

Table1

```
   ID   - Name  - Phone  - GUID
   1      HK      999      HJHHKHJHJHKJH8788 
   2      RK      888      OONMNy7878HJHJHSD
   3      SK      777      POMSDHBSNB775SD87
   4      PK      666      HRBMASJMN76448NDN
```

In `Table2` XML column, I want to update the `ID` node with the new GUID value without changing the element name.

So now the XML would be

```
   <Root>
    <Data1>
     <ID>HJHHKHJHJHKJH8788</ID>
     <Name>HK</Name> 
     </Data1>
    <Data1>
     <ID>OONMNy7878HJHJHSD</ID>
     <Name>RK</Name>
     </Data1>
    </Root>
```

This will happen for all rows in `Table2`.

Please help me with the query for this.

Comment: marc_s, i have knowledge about selecting xml values based on condition, but no idea how to udate a value that is a part of another table.

Comment: Basically somthing like this:

        Update table2 set XMLCol.Modify('Root/Data1/ID') = (Select                  GUID From Table1 Where ID = XMLCol.Query('Root/Data1/ID'))

Can you help me with the exact query.

Comment: Can there be more than one row in table2? Can the id from table1 be reused more than one time in the XML for one row in table2? Can the same id be reused in more than one row in table2?

Comment: Yes there are more than 1 row in table2. Yes the ID Column can be used more than one time in the XML but in diff Blocks of Nodes. By Block i mean Data1 Node and elements in it.

Comment: Yes, but can the same id **value** be reused?

Comment: And how many rows do you have in the tables? How many Data1 nodes on average do you have per row in the XML?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to update the XML in more than one place at a time so you have to do this in a loop of some kind. The best I could come up with was to extract the ID's from the XML in `Table2` and join against `Table1.ID` to produce a temp table that holds `Table2.ID` ordinal position of the `Data1` node in the XML (`OrdPos`) and the new `GUID` value.

Then you can loop over the max number of nodes present in the XML column and do the update.

```sql
-- Variable used to loop over nodes
declare @I int 

-- Temp table to hold the work that needs to be done.
create table #T
(
  ID int, -- ID from table2
  OrdPos int, -- Ordinal position of node Data1 in root
  GUID uniqueidentifier, -- New ID
  primary key (OrdPos, ID)
)

-- Shred the XML in Table2, join to Table1 to get GUID
insert into #T(ID, OrdPos, GUID)
select T2.ID,
       row_number() over(partition by T2.ID order by D.N) as OrdPos,
       T1.GUID
from Table2 as T2
  cross apply T2.XMLCol.nodes('Root[1]/Data1') as D(N)
  inner join Table1 as T1
    on T1.ID = D.N.value('(ID/text())[1]', 'int')

-- Get the max number of nodes in one row that needs to be updated
set @I = 
  (
    select top(1) count(*)
    from #T
    group by ID
    order by 1 desc
  )

-- Do the updates in a loop, one level at a time
while @I > 0
begin
  update T2
  set XMLCol.modify('replace value of (/Root[1]/Data1[sql:variable("@I")]/ID/text())[1] 
                     with sql:column("T.GUID")')
  from Table2 as T2
    inner join #T as T
      on T2.ID = T.ID
  where T.OrdPos = @I

  set @I = @I - 1
end

drop table #T
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/987e0/2)

Answer (score 0):

I got one of them to update.

Close, but no cigar.  But it's end of the day.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#XmlHolderTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #XmlHolderTable
end



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ScalarHolderTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #ScalarHolderTable
end



CREATE TABLE #ScalarHolderTable
(
ScalarKey int not null , 
Name varchar(16) , 
Phone varchar(16) , 
UUID uniqueidentifier 
)


CREATE TABLE #XmlHolderTable
(
XmlSurrogateIdentityKey int not null identity (1001, 1), 
TheXml xml
)


INSERT INTO #ScalarHolderTable 
( ScalarKey , Name , Phone , UUID )
            select  1   ,  'HK' ,    999 , NEWID() 
union all   select  2   ,  'RK' ,    888 , NEWID()
union all   select  3   ,  'SK' ,    777 , NEWID()
union all   select  4   ,  'PK' ,    66  , NEWID()


-- Declare XML variable

DECLARE @data XML;

-- Element-centered XML

SET @data = N'


 <Root>
    <Data1>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>HK</Name> 
    </Data1>
    <Data1>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Name>RK</Name>
    </Data1>
</Root>

';


INSERT INTO #XmlHolderTable ( TheXml) values ( @data )



select TheXml.value('(//Data1/ID)[1]','int') ,  * from #XmlHolderTable


SELECT Data.Col.value('(.)[1]','Int') AS Id
FROM #XmlHolderTable xmlHolder
CROSS APPLY
TheXml.nodes('//Data1/ID') AS Data(Col)

/*
SELECT Data.Col.value('(Id)[1]','Int') AS Id
FROM @Data.nodes('/Root/Data') AS Data(Col)
*/



declare @counter int
select @counter = 0

/*
WHILE ( 
            exists ( select top 1 null
                    From
                        #XmlHolderTable xmlHolder
                    CROSS APPLY
                    TheXml.nodes('//Data1/ID') AS Data(Col) , #ScalarHolderTable scalarHolder
            Where
                ISNUMERIC (     Data.Col.value('(.)[1]','varchar(40)')      ) > 0 

                    )
    )
BEGIN

    select @counter= @counter + 1
    print '/@counter/'
    print @counter
    print ''
*/



UPDATE 
   #XmlHolderTable
SET 
   TheXml.modify('replace value of (//Data1/ID/text())[1] with sql:column("scalarHolder.UUID")') 

--select Data.Col.value('(.)[1]','Int') as MyValue , scalarHolder.ScalarKey

From
    #XmlHolderTable xmlHolder CROSS APPLY TheXml.nodes('//Data1/ID') AS Data(Col) 
    , #ScalarHolderTable scalarHolder
Where
    Data.Col.value('(.)[1]','Int') = scalarHolder.ScalarKey


/*
END
*/



select * from #ScalarHolderTable
select TheXml from #XmlHolderTable




IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#XmlHolderTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #XmlHolderTable
end



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ScalarHolderTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #ScalarHolderTable
end
```

Comment: Thanks granadaCoder, but as you said it just updated 1 value in the xml where as other blocks also should get updated. I am trying to use your approach to complete this. will post it if i succeed.

yes  Mikael Eriksson, the value can be repeated. for ex.

 **
<Root>
<Data1>
<ID>2</ID>
<Value>China</Value>
</Data1>
<Data1>
<ID>1</ID>
<Value>USA</Value>
</Data1>
<Data1>
<ID>1</ID>
<Value>India</Value>
</Data1>
</Root>**

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely want to modify current xml? because if you can just generate it from your data, it will be much simplier:

```
update Table2 set
     XMLCol =
     (
         select T1.GUID as ID, T1.Name as Name
         from T2.XMLCol.nodes('Root/Data1') as T(C)
             inner join Table1 as T1 on
                 T1.ID = T.C.value('ID[1]', 'int') and
                 T1.Name = T.C.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(10)')
         for xml path('Data1'), root('Root'), type
     )
from Table2 as T2
```

see [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2cf8/5) example

**update** Ok, as far as I understand, each Data1 have only one ID. Then you can do this:

```
declare @temp table(ID int, T1_ID int, XMLcol xml)

-- split xml, each ID goes in own row    
insert into @temp
select ID, T.C.value('ID[1]', 'int') as ID, T.C.query('.') as XMLCol
from Table2 as T2
    outer apply T2.XMLCol.nodes('Root/Data1') as T(C)

-- modify xml    
update @temp set
    XMLCol.modify('
        replace value of (Data1/ID/text())[1]
        with sql:column("T1.GUID")
    ')
from @temp as T
    inner join Table1 as T1 on T1.ID = T.T1_ID

-- modify original table    
update Table2 set
   XMLCol =
   (
       select (select T.XMLcol)
       from @temp as T
       where T.ID = T2.ID
       for xml path(''), root('Root'), type
   )
from Table2 as T2
```

Comment: Roman thanks for the reply. My XML is about 300-400 lines, and to make it easy to understand i made this simpler xml trying to replicate the behavior i need.

Comment: updated with another possible solution (if you have only on ID for each Data1)